# How to use something similar to `docker.for.mac.localhost` in Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-18.04

I need to use a name instead of my IP or localhost, is it possible to get something similar to `docker.for.mac`?

**UPDATE**
My use case is that I am running WSO2 API manager on localhost:8243 and 9443. I am running a docker image and in that container (8443), it needs to access the APIs deployed in API Manager.

When I use `--net=host` and use "localhost" in the docker component (where I have to define API Url), I get the error

`x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: Oh! I see. In that case, there's a similar solution (with an host alias) for your use case, but internally within your docker container. I'm adding a new complete answer for this then.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no direct equivalent.

If you're trying to access another port (`:PORT`) on the host, you can run the second container with `--net=host` and access the first service on `localhost:PORT` from inside the container.

If that doesn't work, another solution that I read recently is to pass the host's DNS|IP into your container when you start it and then reference use the variable to access the host from within the container:

```sh
docker run ... --env=HOST=[[YOUR-HOST-ADDRESS]] ...
```

Comment: When I use `--net=host` and use `localhost:port` to access the hosted API's from within the container, it gives me `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error. Any idea on fixing it?

Comment: That's a separate issue. Have a look at this: https://wso2.com/api-management/install/docker/community/get-started/

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use a name instead of my IP or localhost

If that part is what you're actually looking for, you can achieve it easily by adding an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file, right there together with the one for `localhost` (which is an "alias" of your 127.0.01)

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.0.1     yourfancydomain.com
127.0.0.1     asmanyalias-asyou.wish
```

Then just go to your browser and go directly to that address, with the port that you should have already been sharing in your docker container

---

Explaining a bit more the thing about the docker port:

When you start your container, you can bind a port in your host to any port of your dockerized service that you need to access from *outside*:

```
docker run --name nginx -p 8080:80 nginx
```

this will allow you to use your `8080` port to access the `80` port of the service running inside your container.

So... after appending your localhost *alias* with your custom local domain, you can access your nginx service (in the example above) by hitting:

```
your-custom-domain:8080
```

If the port that you bind to the docker service is exactly `80` (`-p 80:80`) then you can even use only the custom domain (with no port at all)

```
your-custom-domain
```

Answer (score 1):

> For the use case when you want your containerized services to be able to access to another service running (externally) in your host, but with a custom hostname instead of the ip of "localhost" (with or without the --net=host):

You can achieve this by including an *extra host* to the container with the [`--add-host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host) parameter, in one of two possible ways (to your convenience):

1. With the IP of your actual Host (using `--net=host`)

```
docker run -it --net=host --add-host=wso2-api:$YOUR-HOST-IP consumer/service
```

2. With the IP of the Docker Host (directly inside your *docker0* network)

```sh
docker run -it --add-host=wso2-api:$DOCKER_HOST_IP consumer/service
```

In both cases, your containerized service will be using that custom address (*wso2-api* in my example) and (since that hostname will be included in the container's `/etc/hosts` file) that custom hostname will properly resolve to the actual ip-address that you need. But the requirement on the matching hostname (in your case, because you need to match the name in the certificate) will be satisfied.

---

How to determine that `DOCKER_HOST_IP`?

Manually: you can just list all of your current assigned IP addresses, to find the one corresponding to the *docker0* network:

```
ip -4 addr
```

or even better by directly filtering the one that you want:

```
ip -4 addr show docker0
```

You'll get an output similar to this:

> 3: docker0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
>
> inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
>
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And copy the ip that appears there after `inet`

---

Automatically: I use this single script to directly grab my current docker host IP (especially useful when testing with different docker nodes):

```
DOCKER_HOST_IP="$(ip -4 addr show docker0 | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1 )"
```

---

Now you can execute a really fast proof-of-concept just by starting a simple alpine container:

```
docker run -it --add-host=wso2-api:$DOCKER_HOST_IP alpine
```

and.. once there in the `sh` prompt, just try to reach your running api service with:

```
nc -zv wso2-api 8243
```

Enjoy! :)

Comment: I used both above commands with "localhost.com" as the custom hostname, with no luck. I keep getting a "client timeout error" from the container (webapp). But when I access the API on localhost.com from inside the container, I get the results successfully.